# Bezier path by filling path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I have a bezier path that comes into my program having been created from an SVG and the problem is it is just an outline. I need to perform hit detection on it, anywhere on the interior of the shape. Is there an equivalent of `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` for filling it?

Answer (score 2):

CGContextFillPath will fill a path within a context when it is drawn.

Comment: I'm trying to do this but I keep getting an invalid context error. Do you see anything wrong with this?

CGContextRef context =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddPath(context, _path.CGPath);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGPathRef myPath = CGContextCopyPath(context);

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this within a 

`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`

If so, posting the entire drawRect would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` takes a path and returns a new path describing the outline of the shape that would be formed when stroking that path. It returns a `CGPathRef`. So if you can perform hit detection on the results of that, then you can perform them directly on your original path. You don't need a conversion.

Supposing I've misunderstood the question, you can use [`CGPathContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint) to test whether a point is inside a path. Use that directly on what you get from your SVG.